# Is there any alternative for Daphne as a ASGI for django1.9 and python2.7

Tags: django

I am currently using 'Daphne' as ASGI for my app in django(1.9) and was facing some issues. Is there are any alternatives for 'Daphne'?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.